# Python: semantic differences between pool.map and map?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, documentation

I have a function that takes one argument, saves a file to a fixed directory, and returns `None`. I want to use `multiproccessing.Pool.map` to execute this function in parallel over many arguments. Will this actually work for functions that don't return a value?

I'm asking because the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) says that `Pool.map` is equivalent to the built-in `map`, but `map(fcn, arg_list)` does not actually execute the function calls until its results are iterated over. In my case there is no point iterating over the results, which are `None`.

Is the documentation incorrect in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the docs are a little out of date. The built-in `map` became an iterable along the way, but `Pool.map` (still) returns a list. So the `multiprocessing` machinery *is* iterating over the results returned, in order to build that list (yes, they all happen to be `None` in your case, but the list is built regardless of what the results are).

You don't *need* to iterate over that list too, but I suggest doing so anyway: then the code will be robust against, say, a future release that may change `Pool.map()` too to return an iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Python's built-in `map` doesn't execute the function until it's iterated over because the result of a `map` call is a generator...

`multiprocessing.Pool.map` will submit tasks for execution immediately.